# Есть ли в pycharme расширения, похожие на better comments в vscode?

Tags: pycharm, поиск-программ

Я пыталась нагуглить, но ничего не нашла. Я сейчас сижу в вс код, и мне очень нравятся комментарии, которые я сама для себя настроила с помощью расширения. И мне интересно, есть ли что-то похожее в пайчарм?

Comment: PyCharm из коробки подсвечивает комментарии с TODO и FIXME (возможно еще что-то умеет подсвечивать), мне обычно этого достаточно. Расширения аналогичного better comments вроде бы нет.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках TODO можно добавить новый шаблон, настроить различные цвета. Получится почти похоже) File, settings, editor, TODO, нажать плюсик в patterns.

Comment: Это скорее комментарий, а не качественный ответ. Следует описать подробнее, по возможности привести  пример.

Comment: Извините, но это именно ответ. Мне нужно расписать последовательность куда нажать? File, settings, editor, TODO, нажать плюсик в patterns. Это больше похоже на инструкцию для детей, я им так пишу. Считаю что взрослых людей достаточно направить в нужную сторону.